# Calculating values based on the results of other values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a little program to help with determining if a new weld is covered by an existing weld procedure. The logic goes like this:

A weld procedure test needs a test piece. If that test piece passes it means the company can weld certain ranges of materials.

If the `thickness` of the plate is <= 3:
  you can weld from 0.7 * `thickness` to 2 * `thickness`

If 3 < `thickness` < 30 you can weld from 0.5 * `thickness` to 2 * `thickness`.

If `thickness` is > 30 you can weld anything greater than 5.

The `throat_thickness` value in `results` dict depends on whether runs is 's' (single) or 'm' (multi).

The problem I have is that if runs == 'm' (for multi) then the value for `throat_thickness` should be 'no restriction'.

```
# fillet weld
def fw_material_qual(throat_thickness, runs):
    results = {}
    if throat_thickness <= 3 and runs == 's':
        results['mat_thickness_qual'] = (0.7 * throat_thickness, 
                                         1.5 * throat_thickness)
        results['throat_thickness_qual'] = (0.75 * throat_thickness,
                                            1.5 * throat_thickness)
    elif 3 < throat_thickness < 30 and runs == 's':
        results['mat_thickness_qual'] = (0.5 * throat_thickness,
                                         2 * throat_thickness)
        results['throat_thickness_qual'] = (0.75 * throat_thickness,
                                            1.5 * throat_thickness)
    elif throat_thickness >= 30:
        results['mat_thickness_qual'] = '5 and up'
        results['throat_thickness_qual'] = throat_thickness
    return results
```

So my question is can I do this in a cleaner way than just having to have more elif's?

```
    elif throat_thickness <= 3 and runs == 'm': # only m has changed!
        results['mat_thickness_qual'] = (0.7 * throat_thickness, 
                                         1.5 * throat_thickness)
        results['throat_thickness_qual'] = 'no restriction' # only this value changed!
```

etc...

Comment: You can combine several if-statements on different levels. Checking `runs` on one level and the thickness on the other. In addition you could write individual function in order to summarize similar/identical code and call those after the `if`-statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
def fw_material_qual(throat_thickness, runs):
    results = {}
    if throat_thickness <= 3:
        results['mat_thickness_qual'] = (0.7 * throat_thickness,
                                         1.5 * throat_thickness)
        if runs == 's':
            results['throat_thickness_qual'] = (
                0.75 * throat_thickness, 1.5 * throat_thickness)
        else:
            results['throat_thickness_qual'] = 'no restriction'
```